# How to pipe two existing file descriptor (one from socket)?

Tags: c

I am doing simple (un)secure shell-like program in C. Server-side is done, it just opens IPv4 socket, listens for connections and when someone connects, std* file descriptors are `close()`'d, client file descriptors are `dup()`'ed, and sh is `execvp()`'ed. Connecting via telnet almost works (telnet additionally sends `^M`).

But now i am stuck on client-side - i don't want to use telnet.
I open socket, get file descriptor, connect, but now I want to `pipe()`.

My code now looks like this:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "util.h" /* die(), something like connected perror() and exit() */

int
main(void)
{
    int serverfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr_in;
    socklen_t serveraddr_len;
    char buf[8192];
    ssize_t rb;

    if ((serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        die("socket:");

    serveraddr_in.sin_port = htons(2221);
    serveraddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serveraddr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr_len = sizeof(serveraddr_in);

    if (connect(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr_in, serveraddr_len) < 0)
        die("connect:");

    while (rb = read(0, buf, 8192)) {
        write(serverfd, buf, rb);
        rb = read(serverfd, buf, 8192);
        write(0, buf, rb);
    }

    close(serverfd);
}
```

I tried many combination of using `pipe()`, `dup()`, `dup2()` and `close()`, but program always ends after `pipe()`ing. What should I do to not use `write()` and buffers, but `pipe()`?

Comment: Not your issue, `while(rd = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))>0) {` you should test for positive value, on error rd will be `-1`

Comment: I temporarily rewrote it like this: `while (rb = read(0, buf, 8192)) {
  if (rb > 1)
   write(serverfd, buf, rb);
  rb = read(serverfd, buf, 8192);
  if (rb > 1)
   write(0, buf, rb);
 }`

Comment: `while(rd = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))>0)` has precedence issues.